# Both '==' operator and Equals/compareTo method not working

Tags: java

I am trying to accept an array of numbers and output if the the numbers entered are distinct or not. I checked the earlier questions regarding this:

1)**using '==' operator** doesn't give me the correct output i.e. if the enter "2,3,4" as the command line arguments (inputs), it still returns that the "numbers are not distinct". The program could be compiled and runs in this case, but doesn't give the correct output.

2) **using the 'equals' and 'compareTo' methods** returns an error while compiling that, "int cannot be dereferenced!" The complilation itself is not successful here.

My code is as follows:

```
class DistinctNoCheck
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   int temp = 0;
        int [] a = new int [10];
        for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++)
        {
            a[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            temp = a[i];
            for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++)
            {
                if((a[j] == temp) && (!(i == j)))
                {
                    System.out.println("Numbers are not distinct!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Numbers are distinct!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: `a.length` is 10, regardless of how many arguments you passed on the command line

Comment: `"2,3,4"` as the command line argument will only give you one argument in the args array, you should enter `"2 3 4"`

Comment: @x4rf41 I think the OP means `"2 3 4"`, otherwise it would throw a `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: `(!(i == j))` should be written `i != j`. It's disturbing my eyes.

Comment: @x4rf41 Yes, as ZouZou said, i meant "2 3 4"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `a.length` which is 10. You should use `args.length` while iterating over the array.

Replace

```
for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++)
```

with

```
for(int j=0;j<args.length;j++)
```

Same goes for loop with i variable.

Comment: Big mistake! Thanks! I was trying to compare an uninitialized array values in a[] array, right?  Just making sure if my realization is correct..! :)

Comment: Precisely. When you declare an int array all entries are initialized to 0. Then you add some values to array but rest are still 0 which you are comparing leading to erroneous result.